# formal way of saying "I want to"

Tags: formality

I’m writing a piece of mail to the manager of some other company, and I wanted to ask him:

> On a different note, I wanted to know how you are doing [*something*].

I was wondering, is there a more formal way of saying *I want to know*?

Would it be correct to say *I am keen to know*?

Comment: From your comment, it seems *interested* or *curious* may be what fits better: "I am curious about how you are doing *sth.*" or "I am interested in how you are doing *sth.*"

Comment: well, he asked me if there is anything else I wanted to know about the procedure of them doin smth, and then I wrote a list of relevant question regrading the procedure, but I wanted to ask some "not-very-relevant" which still could have affect the procedure, I went with _on a different note, I would also like to know..._ and I sent the email... but _curious_ and interested seem fine too. cheers mate.

Comment: mrz: I've edited your question some. Let me offer you a pointer, since you're new. When people ask for clarifications, try editing the question, instead of leaving comments. If something isn't clear to one person, chances are it won't be clear to others. Avoid making it so everyone must read through all your comments to fully understand what you're asking by putting your clarifying remarks in the question itself. Also, brevity is not always good here, be specific about _why_ you have a question about language. Did you think your initial phrasing sounded too impolite? Too demanding? Not fluent?

Comment: @Kris May the Lords of the Sith be visited upon thee, good sir!

Comment: @mrz I’ve edited your question to improve the formatting and clarity a bit; hope that’s ok with you.  I should note here that *keen* is a tad bit old-fashioned sounding.

Comment: @tchrist Suggesting that using *sth.* for *something* is stilted/ esoteric/ archaic? It is indeed in use today.

Comment: @Kris It’s a foreignerism.  I have never seen it used in any of my English texts.  It smacks of ESL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, *I want to know* is perfectly valid. If it’s politeness you’re trying to achieve, you could say *I would like to know*.

This transforms what might have been interpreted as a demand into a request.

An alternative word would be *enquire*, such as in *I would like to enquire*.

Comment: Actually, I don’t think that *enquire* works here.

Comment: You could say something like: *On a different note, I wanted to inquire as to how you are doing [something]*.

Answer (score 2):

You can precede *to know* with all sorts of verbs. Which you choose depends on the context, and the precise degree of formality and politeness you are striving for. In many contexts, including formal ones, *I want to know* may well serve the purpose, but occasionally you may, for example, want to write *I should like to know*. It’s really not possible to say more than that without knowing the purpose of the text you have in mind.

Comment: I'm writing an email to manager of some other company, and wanted to ask him: "On a different note, I wanted to know how you are doing smth"

Comment: That could be ok, but I don't understand _how you are doing smth_.

Comment: mrz wants to know *how (the addressee) is doing something* -- the way he is carrying it out, perhaps.

Comment: you're right Kris.

Comment: Certainly *I should like to know* sounds more formal, and rather more demanding, than *I’m keen to know* does. Part of that is the use of the “old” (?) 1st-person *I should* over *I would*, but another is the lack of contraction.  My unresearched, gut feel is that  the *keen* construct is comparatively rare, at least in North America. But normal speech would just be *I’d like to know*, which is not quite so stiffly demanding.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative expression for *I want to know* could be something like *I enquire*, *I seek*, *I investigate*, etc.

There’re lots of ways to say it, but you may have to decide which suits you best based on your actual context.